# Add delegate and dataSource for extension view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

First of all, I'm not sure the name of it is "extension view", please look at the screenshot, I mean the view with the yellow background.

[image: Screenshot]

I have made a custom table view in this view, and I did all the configurations, the problem is, in the end, I have to add delegate and dataSource for it.

Let's call the table cell inside of the view "OptionTableView".

I wrote these lines the viewdidload of the view controller  (the controller that is inside the iPhone frame in the screenshot),

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    OptionTableView.delegate = self
    OptionTableView.dataSource = self        
}
```

but it crashes the app with this error:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

Because it's UiView, I can't make a new file with a type of UIControlView for it.

Could you help me? How I can add delegate and  dataSource for this extension UIView or whatever is called, that let me to use tableview inside it?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hi, Is `OptionTableView` an `IBOutlet` from your `UIViewController`? Can you share more about your class?

Comment: hii you can upvote answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you not add protocol of tableview. I write a code for this:-

```
  import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var table_view: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        return cell
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table_view.dataSource = self
        table_view.delegate = self
    }

}
```

[image]